# Scrollable widget in Android

Tags: android, widget, scroll

How to create scrollable widget for android 2.2 after android 3 widget support scrolling but in before android 3.0 it will not support but in the play store some application support scrolling in widget how thay work...
please answer...

Comment: have you tried scrollview?

Comment: @Android Priya Scrolling is not supported below 3.0 in widget